# Blazor Server component not rendering on ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I want to use Blazor Component in my ASP.NET MVC App.
So, I follow article like this one : https://fizzylogic.nl/2019/08/18/integrating-blazor-in-an-existing-asp-net-core-application/

The behavior is quite strange, because I have no errors in my console, and my breakpoint put in  `OnInitializedAsync` is fired, but I never reach my breakpoint in `OnAfterRenderAsync`...

I put breakpoints in `BuildRenderTree` & `OnParametersSet`, all of them are fired. My parameters are correctly set, and the `ShouldRender` method returns true.
I also add a `StateHasChanged()` in `OnInitializedAsync`, but my component is still not rendering.

For testing, I replace all my component code by  and still nothing render...

Answer (score 2):

Use the new way of rendering components in mvc razor pages:

```cs
<component type="typeof(Namespace.Pages.Component)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" param-AnyParameter="parameterValue" />
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. In fact, I also already try this, without success...

Comment: Can you share your other setup? I have done the same process in my project and it works fine.

Comment: I've done the same myself, what I don't understand is why all my component's method are called except AfterRenderAsync ...

Comment: That's odd, have you tried this in a blank default new project and if possible share that project on github?

Comment: Figure it out that I was loading blazor script in head section instead of bottom of body. After moving it to bottom of body, my component render !

Answer (score 1):

I discover that loading blazor server client javascript file MUST be done in the bottom of the file. I was loading it in the  of my HTML, which makes my component not rendering.

Moving it to my Scripts section of my razor view make it works !